# How to justify the caption of a table?

Tags: tables, justification

I want to let the label of the caption on the leftmost while the text in the center, I tried this code but only to see both label and text being justified into the center.

```
\DeclareCaptionFormat{myformat}{\raggedright{ #1#2}\centering{#3}\par}
\captionsetup{format=myformat,labelsep=space ,singlelinecheck=no}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of a code snippet.

Comment: If the caption is only one line, you could use `{\rlap{#1#2}\hfill #3\hfill}`.  If the caption is over one line, centering is moot.